# knockout js - subscribe is not updating <select> options

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout JS. I have two `<select>`'s. One has regions, and the other has towns within the selected region. When the user selects a region, the towns select is supposed to update with the towns for that region. However in my website it does not. Why is that? Here is my code:

```
interface iGetAreas {
        _areasList: Array<string>;
        _areas: KnockoutObservableArray<string>;
        _selectedArea: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        getAreas(geonameId: string);
    }

    class AreaGetter implements iGetAreas {
        _areasList = [];
        _areas = ko.observableArray([]);
        _selectedArea = ko.observable('');


        getAreas = (geonameId) => {
            this._areasList = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: `http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=${geonameId}&username=elion`
            }).then((allAreasXML) => {
                var allAreasJSON = xml2json(allAreasXML);
                var allAreas = JSON.parse(allAreasJSON);
                if(allAreas.geonames.length) {
                    for (var index = 1; index < allAreas.geonames.length - 1; index++) {
                    this._areasList.push(allAreas.geonames[index].geoname);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(allAreas.geonames) {
                        this._areasList.push(allAreas.geonames.geoname);
                    }
                }
                this._areas(this._areasList);
                $('.tvr-select').each(function() {
                    $(this).multiselect({
                        buttonWidth: '100%',
                        buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 64px;" />',
                        buttonClass: 'none'
                    });
                })
            });
        }
    }

class SearchFilterViewModel {
    _regionGetter: AreaGetter;
    _townGetter: AreaGetter;
    _categories: KnockoutObservableArray<Category>;
    _categoryID:number;

    constructor() {
        this._categoryID = 1;
        this._categories = ko.observableArray([
            new Category("Vegan Meat", 1), 
            new Category("Vegan Dairy", 2), 
            new Category("Confectionary", 3),
            new Category("Baking", 4),
            new Category("Restaurants", 5),
            new Category("Fashion", 6)
        ]);
        this._regionGetter = new AreaGetter();
        this._townGetter = new AreaGetter();
        this._regionGetter.getAreas("2186224");
        this._regionGetter._selectedArea.subscribe(this._townGetter.getAreas.bind(this._townGetter));
    }

    logMyStuff = function() {
        console.log(this._townGetter._areasList);
        console.log(this._regionGetter._areasList);
        console.log("stuff");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var _searchFilterViewModel: SearchFilterViewModel = new SearchFilterViewModel();
    var _searchFilterForm = $("#find-vegan-products-page").find("form")[0];
    ko.applyBindings(_searchFilterViewModel, _searchFilterForm);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="find-vegan-products-page" class="full-size container-fluid" style="height:900px; padding: 70px 40px 40px 40px;">
            <!-- TODO: Make blackand white video section a bit shorter -->
                <h1 style="margin:0px 0px 20px 0px; color: dimgray;">FILTER YOUR SEARCH</h1>
                <button style="width:400px;height:400px;" data-bind="click: logMyStuff"></button>
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?
                            echo RegionSelect::display();
                            echo TownSelect::display();
                            //echo CategorySelect::display();
                            ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div id="go-button" 
                                class="with-border clickable" 
                                href="#find-vegan-products-page" >
                                <h5  class=" text-center medium-text">GO</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
```

selects are done by php templates but here is the output:

```
    <select class="tvr-select" data-bind="options: _regionGetter._areas,
                optionsText: 'name',
                optionsValue: 'geonameId',
                value: _regionGetter._selectedArea,
                optionsCaption: 'REGION'
                " style="display: none;"><option value="">REGION</option><option value="2193734">Auckland</option><option value="2182560">Bay of Plenty</option><option value="2192628">Canterbury</option><option value="4033013">Chatham Islands</option><option value="2190767">Gisborne</option><option value="2190146">Hawke's Bay</option><option value="2179671">Manawatu-Wanganui</option><option value="2187304">Marlborough</option><option value="6612108">Nelson</option><option value="2185978">Northland</option><option value="6612109">Otago</option><option value="2182501">Southland</option><option value="2181872">Taranaki</option><option value="2181818">Tasman</option><option value="2180293">Waikato</option><option value="2179538">Wellington</option>
            </select>

<select class="tvr-select" data-bind="options: _townGetter._areas,
            optionsText: 'name',
            optionsValue: 'geonameId',
            value: _townGetter._selectedArea,
            optionsCaption: 'TOWN'
            " style="display: none;"><option value="">TOWN</option><option value="2193772">Ashburton District</option><option value="7910036">Christchurch City</option><option value="7910044">Hurunui District</option><option value="7910046">Kaikoura District</option><option value="7910050">Mackenzie District</option><option value="7910060">Selwyn District</option><option value="2181134">Timaru District</option><option value="7910069">Waimakariri District</option>
        </select>
```

Notice I'm trying to run a function called `logMyStuff` but it never runs when I click the button. I want to find out if townGetter._areas is full of areas

Comment: I've just noticed from my question that the values are in the town select. It is a display issue of the select plugin

Comment: You need a custom binding for the multiselect plugin.

Comment: Maybe this one: https://gist.github.com/ssajous/5823594